# How do I extract Text from Excel into Text Edit, find text in Excel and replace into Text Edit? Automation

Tags: excel, adobe-indesign, textedit

I have a Text file on my Desktop AltText.txt, that contains filenames extracted from InDesign.

I have an Excel file that contains the Alt text descriptions, I typically manuel copy paste from Excel to the Text file.

I trying to figure out if there is more efficient away to get Find filenames in the Excel and extract them to the Text file?

Example of Text File:

```
Forward Collision Alert-4C.ai
Graphic Number : 1

Lane Keep Assist-4C.ai
Graphic Number : 2

Lane Change Alert-4C.ai
Graphic Number : 3
```

Example of Excel File:

```
Column A                          Column B   
Forward Collision Alert-4C.ai     Icon of Forward Collision Alert
```

Thank you,
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Paste the text in a new excel file. > put this formula in sheet2,A1.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&1+(ROW()-1)*3,TRUE)
```

and drag downwards

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Sorry.. Would u mind sharing a sample of the AltText.txt & the excel file with the description? Seems like I cannot reproduce your case exactly (to generate the solution), with my current understanding n assumption. /(-_-)

Comment: any leads so far.. ? I'd like to learn if there is a solution to this.. /(^_^)